# Always outputs "is not in the list" no matter if the string is in the list or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, output

I cannot figure out why the output is always "is not in the list" even when I enter a string that is in the list. I have checked if the variables are passing properly into the LinearSearch function and don't think it has anything to do with my syntax (though I may be wrong). New to programming and this is my first question on stackoverflow so don't be too harsh on me. :)

The Code:

```
def main():
    NameList = []
    found = bool
    for Index in range(0, 4):
        NameList.append(str(input("Enter a name: ")))
    SearchName = input("Please enter the name you want to search for: ")
    found = LinearSearch(NameList, SearchName)
    if found == True:
        print(SearchName,"is in the list.")
    elif found == False:
        print(SearchName,"is not in the list.")

def LinearSearch(NameList, SearchName):
    for Index in range(0, 4):
        if SearchName == NameList[Index]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

main()
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LinearSearch` function is returning `False` if the first name in the list is not the name you're searching for. You have to let it finish looping over the rest of the list, then return `False` if the name was never found.

```
def LinearSearch(NameList, SearchName):
    for Index in range(0, 4):
        if SearchName == NameList[Index]:
            return True
    return False
```

One improvement you can make to your code is to search through the entire list no matter how long it is, instead of only looking at the first four indices:

```
def LinearSearch(NameList, SearchName):
    for name in NameList:
        if SearchName == name:
            return True
    return False
```

(I don't know if the point of the exercise was to write `LinearSearch`, but that can be significantly shortened using Python's [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) operator instead.)